# How do i manage multiple prices on one product that only returns one price per query

Tags: sql, postgresql, supabase

So i have a products table, it holds the product data but I am stuck at something, "price".

Each row of a product should have a corresponding price and not just one price but multiple, some users have a 'vip' membership combined with levels (like vip1, vip2,..) all which is stored on a `vip` table, and i have a db function already to tell if the user is a vip and which level, the db function works by looking at how many `points` the user has and returns which level he or she deserves,

the purpose of multiple prices on one product is to give a special price to users based on multiple prices that corresponds to each vip level, when they query the products table.

so every product will have a default price and special prices that are not mathematically calculated but a special custom prices added when you add a new product.

if a user queries the products table they do that via a View on the products table, the view however shall not return all the prices it should only return one price either the default price or the custom price that is matching the user's vip level using that db function to determine what level is the user, and return a matching price of the product to the user.

the second problem i have is i am unsure how to store those prices on the product table, what column and what datatype, and or if i should create a second table "product_price".

So far, this is the solution i have implemented:

I created a table `product_vip_price`

```sql
create table
  public.product_vip_price (
    id bigint generated by default as identity,
    product_id bigint not null,
    vip_level smallint null,
    price numeric null,
    constraint product_vip_price_pkey primary key (id),
    constraint product_vip_price_product_id_fkey foreign key (product_id) references products (id) on delete cascade
  ) tablespace pg_default;
```

and i added this to my products view as the price column

```sql
  coalesce(product_vip_price.price, products.price) as price
from
  products
  left join product_vip_price on products.id = product_vip_price.product_id
  and product_vip_price.vip_level = user_highest_vip_is()
```

`user_highest_vip_is`

```sql
create
or replace function user_highest_vip_is () returns text as $$ BEGIN RETURN (SELECT max(vip.level) FROM profiles JOIN vip ON profiles.points >= vip.points WHERE profiles.id = auth.uid()); END; $$ language plpgsql security definer;
```

`vip` table

```sql
create table
  public.vip (
    id bigint generated by default as identity,
    level smallint not null,
    points integer not null,
    constraint vip_pkey primary key (id),
    constraint vip_level_key unique (level)
  ) tablespace pg_default;
```

`products table`

```sql
create table
  public.products (
    id bigint generated by default as identity,
    is_category boolean not null default false,
    is_available boolean not null default false,
    is_hidden boolean not null default true,
    is_main boolean null default false,
    created_at timestamp with time zone not null default now(),
    parent_id bigint null,
    min_value integer null default 0,
    max_value integer null default 0,
    metadata jsonb null,
    price numeric null default '0'::numeric,
    constraint products_pkey primary key (id),
    constraint products_parent_id_fkey foreign key (parent_id) references products (id) on delete cascade
  ) tablespace pg_default;
```

`profiles`

```sql
create table
  public.profiles (
    id uuid not null,
    metadata jsonb null,
    authorization jsonb null,
    points integer not null default 0,
    constraint profiles_pkey primary key (id),
    constraint profiles_id_key unique (id),
    constraint profiles_id_fkey foreign key (id) references auth.users (id) on delete cascade
  ) tablespace pg_default;
```

And finally the whole View `(products_view)`:

```sql
create view
  public.products_view as
select
  products.id,
  products.is_main,
  products.is_available,
  products.is_category,
  products.parent_id,
  products.min_value,
  products.max_value,
  coalesce(product_vip_price.price, products.price) as price,
  products.metadata
from
  products
  left join product_vip_price on products.id = product_vip_price.product_id
  and product_vip_price.vip_level = user_highest_vip_is ()
where
  products.is_hidden = false;
```

Edit: using a view `user_highest_vip_level` instead of user_highest_vip_is for performance reasons, suggested by JohnH in the comments.

`products_view`

```sql
create view
  public.products_view as
select
  products.id,
  products.is_main,
  products.is_available,
  products.is_category,
  products.parent_id,
  products.min_value,
  products.max_value,
  from_price_to_currency_price (coalesce(product_vip_price.price, products.price)) as price,
  products.metadata
from
  products
  left join product_vip_price on products.id = product_vip_price.product_id
  and product_vip_price.vip_level = (
    (
      select
        user_highest_vip_level.vip_level
      from
        user_highest_vip_level
    )
  )
where
  products.is_hidden = false;
```

`user_highest_vip_level`

```sql
create or replace view user_highest_vip_level AS
SELECT max(vip.level) as vip_level FROM profiles JOIN vip ON profiles.points >= vip.points WHERE profiles.id = auth.uid()
```

Comment: There shouldn't be repeating groups in a normalized database. There should be an associative (bridge) table that references products and vip levels and provides the appropriate price for each combination. The default price can either be an attribute of the products table or it can be handled as just another price in the products/vip level pricing table.

Comment: @JohnH, that's what i thought about as well, creating a table to define the price of the product and the vip level that the price corresponds to, as well as having a 'price' column in the products table, to use it as default if the query from the new table returns null.

Comment: Consider replacing the function `user_highest_vip_is` with a view to improve performance when querying across multiple users. Using a function requires a separate query for each user. Using a view allows the query optimizer to find more efficient exection plans. I also don't see where the VIP price is being based on a specific user.

Comment: @JohnH, thank you for the suggestion, i have update the question as well as adding the 'profiles' table that represents users.

Comment: If the query is only ever for one user at a time, then there won't be a significant performance difference between the function and view approaches to getting the vip level. My suggestion was intended to make a view that could efficiently support querying for any subset of users and products. Exposing users and their associated maximum vip level in the view facilitates reusing the view for reporting or analysis. This approach reduces the need to duplicate logic across multiple views.